# Freezer not working; only makes quiet sound

Tags: refrigerator, compressor

An old (probably 30-50 years) chest freezer is not working. When plugged in it makes a constant, very quiet sound and does not change temperature.

How could I tell what's wrong with it?  Is it likely to be possible to repair it?

Some pics of the compressor compartment:

[image: pic taken from outside the compressor compartment]

[image: pic from just inside the compressor compartment]

Comment: It's probably trying to die in it's sleep.

Answer (score 3):

Repair (by a licensed refrigeration technician) might be *possible*, but is highly unlikely to be *practical or cost-effective* .vs. replacement with a modern and probably far more efficient unit.

For one thing, the R12 refrigerant that your unit uses is now absurdly expensive.

Answer (score 2):

*Energy savings alone* will pay for a new freezer inside a year, even if you had to pay for it!

FIRST, contact your power company and see if they have any upgrade programs, rebates and the like - many will cost-share and some will even buy you a new one for free.*

Then if that option is exhausted, get yourself a new chest freezer on your own nickel. Still a savings!

---

* At first blush, this seems insane. But if you grind through the macro-economics of buying you a new appliance vs. building new power plants to support your old appliances, this is actually a *net win* at the whole-society level.  For instance if the same institution was paying for both the power plant an the freezer, they would have *direct* financial incentive to upgrade. With separate ownership there's a market inefficiency. Power companies and regulators just got together to correct that.